System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' do Método Construtor
Estou com esse erro ao salvar os dados pelo código        _atividadeRepositorio.Adicionar(atividadeModel);
Tenho a classe AtividadeJSONController que recebe os dados JSON e chama o método Adicionar da classe AtividadeController, e nessa classe AtividadeController possuo um método construtor que faz a injeção de dependência para gravar os dados. Já tentei instanciar por vários modos, mas todos ocorrem esse erro. O único código que funcionou foi quando passei o parâmetro _atividadeRepositorio na instanciação da classe principal, AtividadeJSONController atividadeJSONController = new AtividadeJSONController(_atividadeRepositorio).
Segue minhas classes:
AtividadeJSONController
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    JSON_Atividade = GetRequestBody().Result;
    AtividadeController atividadeController = new AtividadeController();

    atividadeController.Adicionar(atividadeJSONModel);

    return Ok("Sucess");
}

AtividadeController
public IAtividadeRepositorio _atividadeRepositorio;

public AtividadeController(IAtividadeRepositorio atividadeRepositorio)
{
     
    _atividadeRepositorio = atividadeRepositorio;
    
}

public AtividadeController()
{
    AtividadeController atividadeController = new AtividadeController(_atividadeRepositorio);
}

public bool Adicionar(AtividadeJSONModel atividadeJSONModel)
{
    AtividadeModel atividadeModel = new AtividadeModel();

    AtividadeController atividadeController = new AtividadeController(_atividadeRepositorio);

    atividadeModel.ID = atividadeJSONModel.ID;
    atividadeModel.CONTATOID = atividadeJSONModel.CONTATO.ID;
    atividadeModel.VENCIMENTO = atividadeJSONModel.VENCIMENTO;
    atividadeModel.DURACAO = atividadeJSONModel.DURACAO;
    atividadeModel.DESCRICAO = atividadeJSONModel.DESCRICAO;
    atividadeModel.REGISTROPROCESSO = atividadeJSONModel.REGISTROPROCESSO;
    atividadeModel.CURSOID = atividadeJSONModel.CURSO.ID;
    atividadeModel.RESPONSAVELID = atividadeJSONModel.RESPONSAVEL.ID;
    atividadeModel.RESUMOATUALID = atividadeJSONModel.RESUMOATUAL.ID;
    atividadeModel.CONCLUIDO = atividadeJSONModel.CONCLUIDO;
    atividadeModel.FORMACONTATO = atividadeJSONModel.FORMACONTATO;

    
    _atividadeRepositorio.Adicionar(atividadeModel); **AQUI está ocorrendo o erro**

    bool retorno = false;
    //if (string gravarBanco = "sucesso")
    //{
    //    retorno = true;
    //}
    return retorno;
}


Entendi! Bom, consegui resolver excluindo a classe AtividadeController e adicionando uma classe AtividadeService, e assim consigo estruturar de forma organizada como gostaria. Agora a classe AtividadeService não é um controller, mas sim uma classe que faz o serviço de CRUD, implementei também uma interface para ela, a IAtividadeService, assim consigo passar os dados de uma classe para outra chamando os métodos por injeção de dependência.

A conversa se estendeu e foi movida para o chat.

O erro está acontecendo porque, provavelmente, você não está fazendo a injeção de dependência da maneira correta.
Você precisa registar o IAtividadeRepositorio no seu container de serviços antes de injetar nas classes que deseja usar.
//A injeção é feita na classe Program.cs, porém em versões mais antigas é na Startup.cs
builder.Services.AddScoped<IAtividadeRepositorio, AtividadeRepositorio>();

Após isso, ao injetar no construtor a interface IAtividadeRepositorio, o próprio container de serviços irá servir uma instância da classe para uso.
Lembrando também que você pode configurar o ciclo de vida dessa instância. No caso do exemplo acima estou utilizando o Scoped, que criará uma nova instância de AtividadeRepositorio para cada requisição Http. É possível também utilizar o Transient e Singleton, a escolha deve ser feita com base na sua necessidade.
